# Is there a way to access propTypes and defaultProps of an imported component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

When I look at this page, I can see a table containing the propTypes and defaultProps for a component : http://styleguide.pivotal.io/react_components_alerts.html

I want to do the same thing for a library I am doing.

I have a list of component that I can access using

```
import { A, B, C, D } from 'mylib';
```

Is there a way to access propTypes and defaultProps so I can format the same table automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a static property on the component. So `A.propTypes` and `A.defaultProps` should give you it.

Comment: it doesn't seems to work for propTypes, do you have a jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: @BigDong https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2172/. If it's not working then the imported component doesn't have proptypes.

Comment: For example, my __<HelloWorld />__ component is : `export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string,
  };
  
  return (
    <h1 className={this.props.className}>Hello World!</h1>
  );
};` For some reason, the propTypes after that is undefined.